# C# ComboBox.SelectedValue not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a WinForms application. I have added a datasource to my ComboBox as below:

DataSource:

```
public static Dictionary<byte, string> Ltype = new Dictionary<byte, string>()
    {
        {1 , "Type1"},
        {2 , "Type2"},
        {3 , "Type3"},
        {4 , "Type4"}
    };
```

Combobox Initialization:

```
cmbType.DataSource = new BindingSource(Ltype, null);
cmbType.DisplayMember = "Value";
cmbType.ValueMember = "Key";
cmbType.KeyUp += (s, e) =>
{
   cmbType.DroppedDown = true;
};
```

I set the value of combobox like below but its does nothing it sets the value to "Type1"(as it would have even if I don't use SelectedValue). I cannot programatically set the value. Also when I debug, the value of `cmbType.SelectedValue` is still `null` after the SelectedValue is executed.

```
cmbType.SelectedValue = 2;
```

I have also tried to do something like this but still the same:

```
cmbType.SelectedValue = "2";
```

Please help me if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread here which is working for me:

[Why ComboBox.SelectedValue does not work...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/d791a978-a9b0-41e2-9b90-ba16904ced5f/why-comboboxselectedvalue-does-not-work-before-parentchanged-event?forum=winforms)

I updated my code as below and it is working now:

```
    cmbType.DataSource = new BindingSource(gltype, null);
    //cmbType.DisplayMember = "Key";
    //cmbType.ValueMember = "Value";
    cmbType.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cmbType.ValueMember = "Key";
    cmbType.KeyUp += (s, e) =>
    {
        cmbType.DroppedDown = true;
    };
    *//added new line*
    **cmbType.BindingContext = new BindingContext();**
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to set the default value as type1?

```
   cmbType.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any way I can set the value using the value member? The index will change frequently in my case. Also, it is not only about the default value but even if I want to set the value as per the saved record from database, it is giving same problem.

Comment: if you want to set default value as  {3 , "Type3"}
cmbType.SelectedIndex=Array.IndexOf(Ltype.Values.ToArray(), "Type3");
or
cmbType.SelectedIndex=Array.IndexOf(Ltype.Keys.ToArray(), (byte)3);